# Controlling the size of log file generated by flume itself

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, cloudera, flume

Flume generates log in /var/log/flume folder.
The files there are growing in GBs. How to limit the file size for these logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

under /etc/flume/conf.empty, copy the log4j.properties from it to /etc/flume/conf. Then flume and its extensions will log the way you configured in the log4j.properties.